# Send Data by Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

First I Fetch Array From MYSQl and i have Select input When Change Value Result Shown by Ajax

```
echo "<select onchange='showUser(this.value)'> <option>Select Unit</option>";

                            $query="select * from item_units WHERE item_id='".$item_id."'";
                            $res=mysql_query($query);
                            if(!$res){die(mysql_error());}
                            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                            $item_unit =$row['item_unit'];

                            $query4 = "SELECT unit_name FROM unit WHERE unit_id='".$item_unit."'";
                            $rest4 = mysql_query($query4);
                            if(isset($rest4))
                            $unit_name4 = mysql_result($rest4, 0); 
                            echo "<option value='$item_unit'>$unit_name4</option>";
                            }

                            echo"</select><br /> ";
```

then i Fetch $item_id From mysql

```
$query="select * from items WHERE item_id='".$item_id2."'";
                            $res=mysql_query($query);
                            if(!$res){die(mysql_error());}
                            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                            $item_id=$row['item_id'];}
```

Then USe

```
echo"<script>

function showUser(str) {
if (str == '') {
    document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML = '';
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open('GET','myesso.php?id=$item_id&q='+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

}
      ";

But Value of ID = $item_id had no value Because OF more than value For Each Record

How i can solve it Can i sent it as array ?

Myesso.php

```
Myesso.php 

     <?php
      session_start();
      include "config.php";
      $q = intval($_GET['q']);
      $gid = $_REQUEST['id'];
      $moha = $_SESSION['logid'];

      $query="select * from login WHERE login_id='".$moha."'";
      $res=mysql_query($query);
      if(!$res){die(mysql_error());}
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
      $type =$row['type'];
      $permission =$row['permission'];
       }

     if($type==1){
     $query="select * from client WHERE login_id='".$moha."'";
     $res=mysql_query($query);
     if(!$res){die(mysql_error());}
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
     $level_id =$row['level_id'];
     $area_id =$row['area_id'];
     }
     }elseif($type==2){
     $query="select * from department WHERE login_id='".$moha."'";
     $res=mysql_query($query);
     if(!$res){die(mysql_error());}
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
     $level_id =$row['level_id'];
     $area_id =$row['area_id'];
     }  
     }elseif($type==3){
     $query="select * from clerk WHERE login_id='".$moha."'";
     $res=mysql_query($query);
     if(!$res){die(mysql_error());}
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
     $level_id =$row['level_id'];
     $area_id =$row['area_id'];
     }  
     }

     $sql="SELECT * FROM item_price WHERE unit_id='".$q."' && level_id = '".$level_id."' && area_id ='".$area_id."' && item_id='".$gid."' ";
     $result = mysql_query($sql);
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $price = $rows['price'];    
   echo"<span class='item-price-special'>$price</span>";
    }


    mysql_close();
     ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "more than value For Each Record"?

Comment: Please post the error message you receive when fetching $item_id

Comment: i mean that i featch values of it from database each item have id ana i showing more than item

Comment: while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                                $item_id=$row['item_id'];

Comment: you state: But Value of ID = $item_id had no value Because OF more than value For Each Record
What does the value look like?

Comment: No error message Shown but the $item_id when i get it in myfile it was empty

Comment: value look like number

Comment: So you are saying that xmlhttp.open('GET','myesso.php?id=$item_id&q='+str,true); does not show the expected output ? Instead it shows     xmlhttp.open('GET','myesso.php?id=&q='+str,true);
and the id field is then blank?

Comment: yes  id=blank & q=value

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do with the code above? Maybe you could label each code snippet with it's filename like post.php:[code]

Comment: From the looks of it since you are using `echo "<select onchange='showUser(this.value)'> <option>Select Unit</option>"` I think you are trying to do a __drop down box__ am I right?

Comment: no i do drop box echo "<option value='$item_unit'>$unit_name4</option>";

Comment: my file myesso.php the value of $gid empty

Comment: Is the rest of the code in 1 file?

Comment: Where are you getting $item_id2 from?

Comment: all code in wishlist.php except myesso.php

Comment: Even if you know it or not what you're trying to do is to create a drop down box that will get values from a table in your database. Since you are using two `select` statements shows that what you want or have to do is __two drop down boxes__. So it means you want to get populate the second drop down box based on the value is selected at the first one.

Comment: when i echo $item_id on wishlist.php i have a value but it couldnot sent in myesso.php that the problem

Comment: @hzq he is attempting to create 1 drop-down (select) with multiple options   that have values that correspond to a name in his datatable. His issue is specifically that when his code is executed he does not get the expected output in his javascript of myesso.php?id=ITEM_ID_FROM_SQL&q='+str but instead he is returned with myesso.php?id=&q='+str no data.

Comment: @Chris I see. Then there could be multiple problems with the code. There are quite a number of logical errors such as the one you posted as an answer. Moreover, a `while` probably needs to be used to get his results to be displayed for each value/option.

Comment: His entire script is flawed but it's not my place to drive this off-topic. The question is "why can't I get this action to happen". Im not going to get into his unclean data input or lack of any computational or logical flow.

Answer (score 2):

Try this replace all of mywishlist.php

```
<?php

                        $query2="select * from wishlist WHERE client_id='".$client_id."'";
                        $res2=mysql_query($query2);
                        if(!$res2){die(mysql_error());}
                        while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($res2)){
                        $item_id2 =$rows['item_id'];



                        $query="select * from items WHERE item_id='".$item_id2."'";
                        $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
                        $shop_id =$row['shop_id'];
                        $cat_id =$row['cat_id'];
                        $sub_id =$row['sub_id'];
                        $brand_id=$row['brand_id'];
                        $item_name=$row['item_name'];
                        $item_id=$row['item_id'];
                        $item_img=$row['item_img'];
                        $item_code=$row['item_code'];
                        $item_over=$row['item_over'];
                        $item_des=$row['item_des'];


                        echo "<script>

           function showUser(str) {
       if (str == '') {
     document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML = '';
      return;
      } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
   }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML =                   xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    }
         xmlhttp.open('GET','myesso.php?id=$item_id&q='+str,true);
       xmlhttp.send();
    }
    }
    </script> ";     


                        $query = "SELECT cat_name FROM cat WHERE cat_id ='".$row['cat_id']."'";
                        $rest = mysql_query($query);
                        if(isset($rest))
                        $cat_name = mysql_result($rest, 0);

                        $query = "SELECT brand_name FROM brand WHERE brand_id ='".$row['brand_id']."'";
                        $rest = mysql_query($query);
                        if(isset($rest))
                        $brand_name = mysql_result($rest, 0);

                        $query = "SELECT sub_name FROM subcat WHERE sub_id ='".$row['sub_id']."'";
                        $rest = mysql_query($query);
                        if(isset($rest))
                        $sub_name = mysql_result($rest, 0);




                        }    




                        echo "
                        <tr>
                                <td style='width:500px' class='item-name-col'>
                                    <figure>
                                        <a href='product.php?id=$item_id'><img src='products/$item_img'></a>
                                    </figure>
                                    <header class='item-name'><a href='product.php?id=$item_id'>$cat_name , $sub_name  , $brand_name , $item_name</a></header>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Item Code: $item_code</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </td>


                                <td class='item-code'>
                                <div id='category-list-1' class='collapse in'>
                                    <div class='panel-body'>
                                        <ul class='category-filter-list jscrollpane'>";

                        $query="select * from item_colors WHERE item_id='".$item_id."'";
                        $res=mysql_query($query);
                        if(!$res){die(mysql_error());}
                        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                        $color_id =$row['color_id'];


                        $query = "SELECT color_code FROM color WHERE color_id ='".$row['color_id']."'";
                        $rest = mysql_query($query);
                        if(isset($rest))
                        $color_code = mysql_result($rest, 0);

                        echo "<li><a href='#'><label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox'  id='".$color_id."' name='colors[]' value='".$color_id."'>&nbsp<span style='padding:10px;width:10px;background:$color_code'></span></label></a></li><br />";
                        } 



                                        echo "</ul>
                                    </div><!-- End .panel-body -->
                                </div><!-- #collapse -->";









                             echo "












                               </td>
                                <td class='item-price-col'> <select style='width:150px' class='form-control' onchange='showUser(this.value)'>
               <option>Select Unit</option>";

                        $query="select * from item_units WHERE item_id='".$item_id."'";
                        $res=mysql_query($query);
                        if(!$res){die(mysql_error());}
                        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                        $item_unit =$row['item_unit'];

                        $query4 = "SELECT unit_name FROM unit WHERE unit_id='".$item_unit."'";
                        $rest4 = mysql_query($query4);
                        if(isset($rest4))
                        $unit_name4 = mysql_result($rest4, 0); 
                        echo "<option value='$item_unit'>$unit_name4</option>";
                        }

                        echo"</select><br /> 

                        <div id='txtHint'></div>

                        </td>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80464/discussion-on-answer-by-chris-send-data-by-ajax).

Answer (score -2):

Mywishlist.php

```
<?php

                            $query2="select * from wishlist WHERE client_id='".$client_id."'";
                            $res2 = mysql_query($query2);
                            if(!$res2) { die(mysql_error()); }

                            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($res2)) {
                               $item_id2 =$rows['item_id'];

                               $query = "select * from items WHERE item_id='".$item_id2."'";
                               $res = mysql_query($query);
                               if(!$res) { die(mysql_error()); }

                               while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
                                    $shop_id =$row['shop_id'];
                                    $cat_id =$row['cat_id'];
                                    $sub_id =$row['sub_id'];
                                    $brand_id=$row['brand_id'];
                                    $item_name=$row['item_name'];
                                    $item_id=$row['item_id'];
                                    $item_img=$row['item_img'];
                                    $item_code=$row['item_code'];
                            $item_over=$row['item_over'];
                            $item_des=$row['item_des'];


                            echo "<script>

               function showUser(str) {
           if (str == '') {
         document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML = '';
          return;
          } else { 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
          // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
         xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
       }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML =                   xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        }
             xmlhttp.open('GET','myesso.php?id=$item_id&q='+str,true);
           xmlhttp.send();
        }
        }
        </script> ";     


                            $query = "SELECT cat_name FROM cat WHERE cat_id ='".$row['cat_id']."'";
                            $rest = mysql_query($query);
                            if(isset($rest))
                            $cat_name = mysql_result($rest, 0);

                            $query = "SELECT brand_name FROM brand WHERE brand_id ='".$row['brand_id']."'";
                            $rest = mysql_query($query);
                            if(isset($rest))
                            $brand_name = mysql_result($rest, 0);

                            $query = "SELECT sub_name FROM subcat WHERE sub_id ='".$row['sub_id']."'";
                            $rest = mysql_query($query);
                            if(isset($rest))
                            $sub_name = mysql_result($rest, 0);




                            }    




                            echo "
                            <tr>
                                    <td style='width:500px' class='item-name-col'>
                                        <figure>
                                            <a href='product.php?id=$item_id'><img src='products/$item_img'></a>
                                        </figure>
                                        <header class='item-name'><a href='product.php?id=$item_id'>$cat_name , $sub_name  , $brand_name , $item_name</a></header>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Item Code: $item_code</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </td>


                                    <td class='item-code'>
                                    <div id='category-list-1' class='collapse in'>
                                        <div class='panel-body'>
                                            <ul class='category-filter-list jscrollpane'>";

                            $query="select * from item_colors WHERE item_id='".$item_id."'";
                            $res=mysql_query($query);
                            if(!$res){die(mysql_error());}
                            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                            $color_id =$row['color_id'];


                            $query = "SELECT color_code FROM color WHERE color_id ='".$row['color_id']."'";
                            $rest = mysql_query($query);
                            if(isset($rest))
                            $color_code = mysql_result($rest, 0);

                            echo "<li><a href='#'><label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox'  id='".$color_id."' name='colors[]' value='".$color_id."'>&nbsp<span style='padding:10px;width:10px;background:$color_code'></span></label></a></li><br />";
                            } 



                                            echo "</ul>
                                        </div><!-- End .panel-body -->
                                    </div><!-- #collapse -->";









                                 echo "












                                   </td>
                                    <td class='item-price-col'> <select style='width:150px' class='form-control' onchange='showUser(this.value)'>
                   <option>Select Unit</option>";

                            $query="select * from item_units WHERE item_id='".$item_id."'";
                            $res=mysql_query($query);
                            if(!$res){die(mysql_error());}
                            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                            $item_unit =$row['item_unit'];

                            $query4 = "SELECT unit_name FROM unit WHERE unit_id='".$item_unit."'";
                            $rest4 = mysql_query($query4);
                            if(isset($rest4))
                            $unit_name4 = mysql_result($rest4, 0); 
                            echo "<option value='$item_unit'>$unit_name4</option>";
                            }

                            echo"</select><br /> 

                            <div id='txtHint'></div>

                            </td>
```

Comment: Edit your question; do not add code as an answer; that is not why there is an answer field.

Comment: Stack overflow is not a forum.  You do not post more content as more posts; you edit the original post.